# Cast field in pymongo query

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I feel like this should be trivial.

I have a record like :

`{'f1' : 1, 'f2' , 'aaaa'}`

When I query for that I want to be returned :

`{'f1' : '1', 'f2' , 'aaaa'}`

Where I have simply cast the int as a string. I don't believe I should have to use the aggregation framework to accomplish this.

I imagine there is someway to pass a  JS function but I don't know that magic.

Edit:
Answering my own question to some degree.To do this with aggregation framework. It would be as simple as.

`db.datasets.aggregate({$match : {f1:{$ne:null}}},{ $project : {f1: {$toUpper:"$f1"}, f2 : 1 }})`

Comment: That's an invalid hash you have there

Answer (score 0):

Neither MongoDB nor PyMongo provides a feature like this. You could try adding a ["SON manipulator"](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/son_manipulator.html) to transform the outgoing document (that is, the document being retrieved out of the database). But by far the easiest method is:

```
for doc in db.datasets.find():
    doc['f1'] = str(doc['f1'])
    do_something_with(doc)
```

Comment: This won't work for me as I can't (don't want) to process the result on the client side.
I'll probably end up going with the aggregation approach I posted above.